# how can this missing observation model be extended to include cases where sigma is a function of other variables?

Tags: bayesian, missing-data, markov-chain-montecarlo, beta-distribution, rstan

Richard McElreath's blog entry **[Algebra and the Missing Oxen](http://elevanth.org/blog/2018/01/29/algebra-and-missingness/)** describes a simple missing observation model in RStan. At the end of the blog, he says it can be extended easily to cases in which the parameters themselves (e.g., sigma) are functions of other variables (e.g., age). My question is: can anyone modify the Stan model below to include sigma as a function of another variable such as age (or set of *K* variables)?

```
data {
  int N_children;      // number of children
  int tea[N_children]; // [0,1] observed drinking tea
  int s[N_children];   // [0,1,-1] stabled ox
}
parameters{
  real p_cheat;        // probability tea = 1 | s = 0
  real p_drink;        // probability tea = 1 | s = 1
  real sigma;          // probability s = 1
}
model{
  // priors
  p_cheat ~ beta(2,2);
  p_drink ~ beta(2,2);
  sigma ~ beta(2,2);

  // probability of tea
  for ( i in 1:N_children ) {
    if ( s[i] == -1 ) {
      // ox unobserved
      target += log_mix( 
                  sigma , 
                  bernoulli_lpmf( tea[i] | p_drink ) , 
                  bernoulli_lpmf( tea[i] | p_cheat ) );
    } else {
      // ox observed
      tea[i] ~ bernoulli( s[i]*p_drink + (1-s[i])*p_cheat );
      s[i] ~ bernoulli( sigma );
    }
  }
}
generated quantities{
  vector[N_children] s_impute;
  for ( i in 1:N_children ) {
    if ( s[i] == -1 ) {
      vector[2] log_pox;
      real pox;
      log_pox[1] = log(sigma) + bernoulli_lpmf( tea[i] | p_drink );
      log_pox[2] = log1m(sigma) + bernoulli_lpmf( tea[i] | p_cheat );
      pox = exp(log_pox[1]) / ( exp(log_pox[1]) + exp(log_pox[2]) );
      s_impute[i] = pox;
    } else {
      s_impute[i] = s[i];
    }
  }
}
```

The [blog entry](http://elevanth.org/blog/2018/01/29/algebra-and-missingness/) provides code for the simulated data, and I provide it here for convenience. Let me know if you need more details from the blog provided here?

```
set.seed(1)
N_children <- 51
s <- rbinom( N_children , size=1 , prob=0.75 )
s_obs <- s
s_obs[ sample( 1:N_children , size=21 ) ] <- -1
tea <- rbinom( N_children , size=1 , prob=s*1 + (1-s)*0.5 )

data_list <- list(
  N_children = N_children,
  tea = tea,
  s = s_obs )

library(rstan)
m <- stan( model_code=stan_model , data=data_list )
print( m , probs=c( (1-0.89)/2 , 1-(1-0.89)/2 ) )
```

Output:

```
          mean se_mean   sd   5.5%  94.5% n_eff Rhat
p_cheat   0.48    0.00 0.14   0.26   0.71  3327    1
p_drink   0.93    0.00 0.05   0.84   0.98  4000    1
sigma     0.76    0.00 0.07   0.65   0.87  2924    1
lp__    -44.54    0.03 1.35 -47.17 -43.13  1771    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn the variance for each observation into a transformed parameter,  e.g. as follows:
$$\log sigma_i = \beta_0 + \ldots, $$
where the dots stand for any factors or covariates you want to include in the model. $\sigma_i$ is then the standard deviation for the error term in each observation. To have heteroscedasticity,  one of the terms going into the equation above could be the mean in some potentially transformed way.

You will want to sanity check your priors for the additional model parameters to see that they imply a prior for the standard deviation that you think is reasonable (easy when you just need to consider the distribution of $\exp{\beta_0}$). That will sadly become increasingly difficult the more complex the model for the variance becomes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Just to clarify in the case of a single covariate such as Age, it would look something like: $log _sigma_i_ = \beta_0 + \beta_1 _Age_$

Comment: Yes,  $\beta_0+\beta_1 age_i$.

Comment: Thanks, and so in the context of the model (where sigma is a unit variable representing the probability of an event ~ not variance as you might have assumed), I would need something like: $sigma_i = Beta ( log ( \beta_0 + \beta_1 _Age_i_))$ I think...